# Input Fields update AFTER submit button is clicked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The input fields should NOT directly update the fields (meaning when I type in the input box you should NOT see the badge field update - only after the Submit button is pressed will the fields populate).

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Name Badge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="fName"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="phone">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="lName"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Place of Birth" ng-model="birth"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Favorite Food" ng-model="food">
           </div>
       </div>
       <textarea ng-model="about">Tell us about yourself</textarea><br>
       <button class="btn" type="submit" ng-submit="info()">Submit</button>

       <br><br>


       <br><br><br><br>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6">
               <h3>Name: {{fName}} {{lName}}</h3>
               <h3>Place of Birth: {{birth}}</h3>
               <h3>Email: {{email}}</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6">
               <h3>Phone: {{phone}}</h3>
               <h3>Favorite Food: {{food}}</h3>
           </div>
       </div>
       <textarea>{{about}}</textarea>

   </div>


   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.info = function () {


    $scope.fName = fName;
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.phone = '';
    $scope.lName = '';
    $scope.birth = '';
    $scope.food = '';
    $scope.about = '';

}


}])
```

Can someone look at my code and help me see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Name Badge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="fName"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="phone">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
               <input class="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="lName"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Place of Birth" ng-model="birth"><br>
               <input class="text" placeholder="Favorite Food" ng-model="food">
           </div>
       </div>
       <textarea ng-model="about">Tell us about yourself</textarea><br>
       <button class="btn" type="submit" ng-submit="info()">Submit</button>

       <br><br>


       <br><br><br><br>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6">
               <h3>Name: {{fName1}} {{lName1}}</h3>
               <h3>Place of Birth: {{birth1}}</h3>
               <h3>Email: {{email1}}</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6">
               <h3>Phone: {{phone1}}</h3>
               <h3>Favorite Food: {{food1}}</h3>
           </div>
       </div>
       <textarea>{{about}}</textarea>

   </div>


   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

js file is

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.info = function () {


    $scope.fName1 =   $scope.fName1;
    $scope.email1 =  $scope.email;
    $scope.phone1 = $scope.phone;
    $scope.lName1 = $scope.lName;
    $scope.birth1 =  $scope.birth;
    $scope.food1 =  $scope.food;
    $scope.about1 =  $scope.about;

}


}])
```

Comment: If you want to show updated value only after submit ,then you have to use a separate model.

Comment: oh really? Like create another controller or service?

Comment: No,Create another Object .